# How can I adjust a code of a diagram to draw another diagram?

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd, code, commutative-diagrams

Here is the code of a diagram I have:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % For adding List of Tables and List of Figures to Table of Contents
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
      \def\@oddfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
      \def\@evenfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}}
      \def\@evenhead{\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
      \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
          \fi
        \fi
        ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
          \thesection. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}% apply new definitions

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em]
  & H_{*}(Y)
     & \\
  & H_{*}(\Sigma X\vee \Sigma X)
  \arrow[u,"\nabla_* \circ(f\vee g)_*"] 
  & \\
  H_{*}(\Sigma X)
  \arrow[uur,out=80,in=190,"f_*"]
  \arrow[r]
  \arrow[ur,"i_{1*}"]
  &
  H_{*}(\Sigma X)\times H_{*}(\Sigma X)
  \arrow[u,"i_{1*}\oplus i_{2*}"]
 &
  H_{*}(\Sigma X) 
  \arrow[l]
  \arrow[uul,out=100,in=-10,"g_*"'] 
  \arrow[ul,"i_{2*}"']
  \\
  \end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

And this code displays the following figure:

> [image]

But I need to display this figure also:

> [image]

Any advice about adjusting my code to draw the new figure please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- please, always provide MWE, i.e. small document, which reproduce your problem. For it the most of the provided preamble are irrelevant
- you only need to permutate order of rows, and accordingly change arrows direction, and write new edge labels (i.e. rewrite almost complete diagram code):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
  & H_{\bullet}(Y)
     & \\
  & H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X\vee \Sigma X)
  \arrow[u,"\nabla_* \circ(f\vee g)_*"]
  & \\
  H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
  \arrow[uur,out=80,bend left,"f_*"]
  \arrow[r]
  \arrow[ur,"i_{1*}"]
  &
  H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)\times H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
  \arrow[u,"i_{1*}\oplus i_{2*}"]
 &
  H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
  \arrow[l]
  \arrow[uul,bend right,"g_*"']
  \arrow[ul,"i_{2*}"']
  \\
  \end{tikzcd}
\]

permutated rows and changed arrows directions and labels:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em]
H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
    &   H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)\times H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
        \lar
        \rar
        &   H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)         \\
    &   H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X\vee \Sigma X)
        \arrow[u,"q_{1*}\times q_{2*}" ']
        \arrow[ul,"q_{1*}"]    
        \arrow[ur,"q_{2*}"']
         &                           \\
    &   H_{\bullet}(Y)
        \arrow[u,"c_x" ']
        \arrow[uul,bend left, "q_1\circ c_x"]
        \arrow[uur,bend right,"q_\circ c_x" ']
                &                   \\
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think I had a problem in reversing the arrows as the diagram I wanted is not exactly like the one you gave me by your code.

Comment: @Ups, I overlooking this.  I will correct arrows direction ASAP.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Happy, done. BTW, as you can see, changes are quite straightforward ;-)